# How to implement leadbolt App Icon, Notification or unlocker with phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, leadbolt

Has anyone ever used leadbolt ads such as App Icon, Notification or unlocker with phonegap. 
I need some pointers on how to implement them correctly. I have read the documentation on their site and the readme that came with the plug-in but still couldn't manage to implement it.

I would really appreciate any help offered.
Thanks.

The HTML banner ads work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update has been made to the Phonegap library to support LeadBolt’s advanced ad units and is now available for download in the Help/ FAQ section of LeadBolt. The instructions in this section should explain the integration steps clearly.